# Two Change Events on One Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have two change events on one sheet but it does not trigger the macros when the changes occur in the specific range. What is wrong with my code?

I have one range (D2:D30) that runs a loop through the column and pastes the data on a second sheet in specific cells. The second range (A2:A30) is supposed to erase specific cells when a change occurs.

I have looked through Stack Flow for an answer and I saw various styles but none of them worked.

This is my code.

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
If Not Intersect(target, Range("D2:D30")) Is Nothing Then

Dim wsInfoSheet As Worksheet
Dim wsProofSheet As Worksheet
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim sAcct As String
Dim lngNextRow As Long
Dim sLongName As String

Dim arrRef() As Variant
Dim arrNames() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lngRowInNames As Long
Dim lngFoundName As Long

Set wsInfoSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Info Input")
Set wsProofSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proof")

' Will be used in the Proof sheet
lngNextRow = 4 ' waiting to adjust to normal table format

arrRef = wsProofSheet.Range("A199:L79000").Value
ReDim arrNames(1 To UBound(arrRef, 1) + 1, 1 To 2)

With wsInfoSheet

lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

lngRowInNames = 1
For r = 2 To lngLastRow
  sAcct = .Cells(r, "E")
  'lookup for sAcct in arrRef
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrRef, 1)
    If arrRef(i, 1) = sAcct Then
      sLongName = arrRef(i, 12) '(row i, column 2 from arrRef)
      arrNames(lngRowInNames, 1) = sLongName
      arrNames(lngRowInNames, 2) = lngNextRow
      lngRowInNames = lngRowInNames + 1
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
  'lookup for sLongName in arrNames
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrNames, 1)
    If arrNames(i, 1) = sLongName Then
      lngFoundName = i
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

  'if the name is new
  If arrNames(lngFoundName + 1, 1) = "" Then
    wsProofSheet.Cells(lngNextRow, "E") = sAcct
    wsProofSheet.Cells(lngNextRow, "B") = sLongName
    lngNextRow = lngNextRow + 8   ' would be nicer to just add one row (see  first note)
  'if the name already exists
  Else
    wsProofSheet.Cells(arrNames(lngFoundName, 2), wsProofSheet.Cells(arrNames(lngFoundName, 2), wsProofSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 3) = sAcct
  End If

Next 'r

End With


Dim iCell As Range

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell, Range("A2:A30")) Is Nothing Then
For Each iCell In Range("A2:A30")
    If iCell.Address = Target.Address Then
        Range("C" & iCell.Row).ClearContents
        Range("D" & iCell.Row).ClearContents
        Range("I" & iCell.Row).ClearContents
    End If
Next iCell

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify, you can only have one Change handler. Is that what you have?

Comment: Look at `offset` also, so no need for the if's  `target.offset(0,2).value=""`  You need all this in the `change` event, and then just use your if intersects to select which code to run?

Comment: I need to have the `target.offset(0,2).value=""` becuse it provides a different function. The issue is that under one `Worksheet_Change` I cannot trigger `If` this `Than` conditions.

Comment: @Mamamia93 I was offering the offset as a hint, there is no need for the ifs  If `target` is `a4` then `target.offset(0,2)` would be `c4`

Comment: I think you could reduce your huge `ElseIf` statement to a simple loop

Comment: Would you be able to clarify? I am not understanding. @Nathan_Sav

Comment: @urdearboy what do you suggest?

Comment: I have clarified, read about `offset` "If target is a4 then target.offset(0,2) would be c4"  You are giving each comment <2minutes of your time :)  I think @urdearboy has done it for you now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't answer your issue but this will maybe help you to SHORTEN your code and make it easier to read/debug (*hard to follow code = hard to debug code*)

---

Your entire `ElseIf` statement at the end can be reduced to this loop

```
Dim iCell As Range

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell, Range("A2:A30")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each iCell In Range("A2:A30")
        If iCell.Address = Target.Address Then
            Range("C" & iCell.Row).ClearContents
            Range("D" & iCell.Row).ClearContents
            Range("I" & iCell.Row).ClearContents
        End If
    Next iCell
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I coded something similar in the past but I did not have success. I will try it now and I will let you know how it ends up.

Comment: Any time you find yourself writing very repetitive things (or copypasta) then you are prob coding something that can be done in a loop

Comment: I understand. I am fairly new to VBA, and your help is really appreciated. Now I am trying to figure out the change event issue.